# What to call a symbol that denotes an "undisclosed" given number?

Tags: notation, terminology

Students like to categorize *notations* to pin down their understanding of exactly what these *notations* stand for. Thus, given the expressions $f(x_{0})=f(x)|_{x\leftarrow x_{0}}$, $x=x_0+h$, or $lim_{x\rightarrow x_{0}}$, they like that the *notation* $x$ is in the category of `(global) variables` and that the *notation* $h$ is in the category of `(local) variables`. And, while they do understand that the *notation* $x_0$ stands for a number that is fixed "for the duration", they want to know what is the (name of the) category of "notations" that $x_0$ falls in.

Comment: I encountered this question on the review queue---at least one user has voted to close it.  I chose not to vote-to-close, but I understand the impulse.  As it is currently written, your question might be an appropriate question for [math.se], with the "terminology" tag.  Could you please edit your post to highlight the **educational** issue you are trying to highlight?

Comment: Never heard "local variable" applied to math expressions.

Comment: @XanderHenderson: Not OP but I can absolutely see some educational issues being related to this query. For instance, the limit definition of a derivative, $f'(a)=\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$, always confuses students because we use it to show that, for instance $f'(a)=2a$ when $f(x)=x^2$, so then we turn around and say $f'(x)=2x$. But that's a different $x$ than the one in the limit ... I also wish we had some terminology to use with students regarding these things!

Comment: @BrendanW.Sullivan It is not that I don't see an education / pedagogy question somewhere in what is written, only that as the question is *currently* written, the educational question is non-obvious, and it is not clear whether the asker is concerned with how a term might be used in the classroom, or how it might be used in research.  As I said, I didn't vote-to-close, but some clarification would be good.

Comment: @Brendan W. Sullivan  I completely agree. Not to mention that $f(a)$ is dangerous when $f(x)$ happens to be equal to, say, $ax+b$, or worse, $a$ as in $ax^0$.

Comment: I don't understand what the OP means by global and local variables, or by an undisclosed given number.

Comment: @BrendanW.Sullivan I agree is well. I wonder if $h$ should be thought of as a parameter in this context, fixed to well defined limit where $h=a$. For example, we often define functions that depend on notionally suppressed parameters like $a$, for example $g(x) = \frac{f(x) - f(a)}{x-a}$. We may then specialize these function that certain values like $a=1$ or $a=4$. A limit is then related to a specialization of the parameter to a particular value, say $0$ (infinite limits are a bit trickier). I feel like this squares with the $\delta-\epsilon$ definition, where $\delta$ would be a parameter.

Comment: @BenCrowell I think schremmer is using cop-sci terminology to denote variables that are appear in the definition/computational algorithm for the function but aren't necessary for the definition of the function. For another example $f(x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \hat{f}(t) e^{-i\pi t x}\,dt$ doesn't depend on $t$. In computer science you'd call such a variable "local" since it only appears within the function.

Comment: This may be related to the concept of a  __bound variable__. In first order logic bound variable are variables that are quantified over in a formula, ie $\forall y P(x,y)$. The quantifier here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic#Free_and_bound_variables

Comment: @Ben Crowell  1. I am sure you don't use $x$ and $h$ interchangeably. 2. I am sure you ask your students for the tangent to, say, $f(x)=-2x^3$. They say "Hey, you gotta *give* us a *number* for where." You say "Just go ahead, I will *disclose* what the *number* is when you are done."  3. All trivial of course. Only on "Mathematics *Educators*" do I get this kind of treatment. I quit.

Comment: I think what you call local and global is usually called bound and free variables. For instance in $f(x_0)=\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)$ the $x$ is a bound variable, while $f$ and $x_0$ are free. Roughly bound means you cannot freely assign a value to it, but you can rename it without changing the meaning of the expression. Free variables you can assign values to, but you cannot rename them without changing the meaning.

Answer (score 5):

In this instance I would probably say "Fix an (arbitrary) point $x_0$" and carry on.  The idea is it's initially unknown but after its introduction stays constant which this sounds like it conveys pretty nicely, and I don't think it's worth splitting philosophical hairs over what is a "variable" vs. "parameter", especially in the face of how scope and discharging of variables are rarely precisely dealt with in typical mathematical writing.

Comment: That is an *explanation* of what $x_0$ stands for. I hope the edit makes now clear what it was I was after.